# javascript - how to get date locale to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a localized implementation of a date picker to work, for a while now. I first attempted doing at the application I am working on, to no avail. So I decided to create a small html page and use it on my local httpd to try and get it running and get transfer the working code to my app.

I copied all the CSS and JS files, adjusted the path and tried the implementation. The file is the following:

As you can see, it's very simple. All I want to do here is learn how to use the `bootstrap-datetimepicker`, so I can manipulate data for my main application.

Problem is: if I use jquery-ui's notation `$('#datepicker0').datepicker();` it works. But if I try to use `$('#datepicker0').datetimepicker();` from https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker it doesn't.

I'm pretty sure it's a very basic mistake, but I'm looking at this piece of code for a while now and can't fathom what it is...

Can someone lend me a help here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/beyond.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/pt-br.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datepicker0').datepicker();
    });
  </script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-group date col-sm-3">
        <input id="datepicker0" type="text" name="executionDate" class="form-control"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On the first instance there is no `</input>`. `input` is self ending tag like `<input .. .. . . />`

Comment: OK! That works either way, but my main app uses Thymeleaf and it (I don't know why!) is not responding well to `<input ... />`

Comment: Well I've a **[`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kLms9ep9/)** here for you.. It works well.. Did you check for console errors?

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't see what I got wrong...

Comment: You checked for any console erros?

Comment: I get two messages on console. One says `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`, the other `TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function`.

Comment: Either its totally script error which is preventing `bootstrap datetimepicker` script not to load properly.. Try keeping only necessary scripts required for `timepicker` to work and check if that `SyntaxError` is clearing out?

Comment: Which datetime picker are you using? The error message does not match the javascript you've provided - `$('#datepicker0').datepicker();` vs. `$(...).datetimepicker is not a function` - And the error message would indicate that you either are not loading jquery or the datetime picker library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Solution was as simple as use the right file. How so? I was trying to download the libraries files by right clicking on it and saving it to my computer. What I got instead of the file was the html for the page. I discovered my stupidity quite by accident this morning and got the correct files, by download the zip for the library and, like in a magic trick, it started working... Thanks for your insights and hel